# Codeigniter: cannot upload files from subdirectory to main directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I'm having 2 codeigniter applications one of them in the root and the other is in a sub directory. I'm trying to upload files from the application in the sub sirectory the the images/artists folder in the root (in the main application) but I get

```
ERROR  404 Page Not Found: Images/artists
The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.
```

I run this code in the controller which is used to upload in the sub directory application

```
if (file_exists('../images/artists')) {
     echo 'directory exists - ';
        if (!is_dir('../images/artists')) { 
            echo 'not a dir';
         }
         else{
            echo 'it is a dir';
         }
}
```

And I get "directory exists - it is a dir" and then run the upload code

```
$gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images/artists/');
$config['upload_path'] = $gallery_path;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size'] = '20000';
$config['file_name'] = round(microtime(true) * 1000).'.jpg';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ($this->upload->do_upload('img')) {
    $phot_data = $this->upload->data();
    $photo_name = $phot_data['file_name'];
    $this->resizeImage($photo_name);
     $artist_data['image'] = $config['file_name'];
}
```

//not used here but dows it override and trigger the error?

```
function do_upload() {
    if ($_FILES['photos']['name'][0] != '') {
        $name_array = array();
        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
            $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $value['name'];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $value['type'];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $value['error'];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $value['size'];

            $config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH . 'images/artists/');

            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['max_size'] = '2000';
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];

    }
    redirect('admin/gallery');
}
```

I checked images and artists permissions and they are set to 777 Where's the issue then?

Comment: Where does the error `ERROR  404 Page Not Found: Images/artists` come from? None of the posted code would give you that error so there seem to be more going on than what you're showing us...

Comment: added do_upload function in the question

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot of the same things in the two last scripts. But you also seem to be setting a different upload path. Please edit your question to clarify when which code is used. Also, why not just create the `$config`-array before the foreach-loop and reuse it instead of recreating it on each iteration?

Comment: When you test it, you're using `file_exists('../images/artists')` but when you're setting it, you're using `realpath(APPPATH . '../images/artists/')`. Check that those are the same. Or better yet, set `$path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images/artists/');` and then use that variable to test if the folder and writable and use it for setting the upload folder. Then you know that the folder you test and set are identical.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet only checks if the directory *exists*, but you want to confirm that it is writable (i.e. that you can put new files into it).

Check [is_writable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) for more details.  To fix the problem you'll need to run [`chmod 600 /path/to/images/artists`](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/unix/command/chmod-permissions-flags-explained-600-0600-700-777-100-etc) on the server.

Comment: **Note:** If you change it to `600`, the owner of the folder must be the user the web server uses (usually `www-data`).

Comment: changed to 600 and 644 but still the same

Comment: If you alter your first snippet to use `is_writable` instead of `is_dir`, does it return `true`?

Comment: Thanks I edited the path and it worked though I checked the same path before but didn't work!!!!